# Binding внутри Application.Resources

Tags: wpf, .net

В разметке ресурсов приложения есть TextBlock. Как я могу сделать привязку текста для этого элемента, если в Application нет свойства DataContext?

```
<Application.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>        
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Элементы в ресурсах хранить особого смысла нет, т. к. элементы могут находиться только в одном месте в дереве. Обычно в ресурсах хранят шаблоны/стили. Ну и с привязкой никаких проблем нет — как DataContext появится, привязка к нему автоматически сработает.

Comment: @АндрейNOP то есть, когда элемент будет извлечен из ресурсов и использован в какой-либо форме, то его содержимое автоматически свяжется с DataContext того элемента, где он будет использован?

Comment: По идее – да, пробуйте.